# FOSUserbundle login form not redirecting to route

Tags: symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle, symfony-routing

I'm using FOSUserBundle and i want to redirect users to homepage after login. I'm using annotations to define my routes and i have named my homepage route "homepage". However, i get the error "no route found for homepage" after login. When i remove the `default_target_path` and `always_use_default_target_path` information from my `security.yml` file (as shown below), the form redirects me to a blank page after login. When i add it back (specifying the route), i get the no route found error.

Here's my `routing.yml`

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation

fos_user:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Here's `security.yml`

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            require_previous_session: false
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            homepage //the name of my route
```

And here's the default Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
   {

      return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');


   }
}
```

I've cleared cache several times using several commands but still no luck. What could be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the path of your route rather than its name for your `default_target_path`,
 e.g. `default_target_path: /`

Of course, you should be able to browse the `homepage` route normally with an authenticated user.

If it works, execute the `php app/console debug:router` command.
If you doesn't see the route `homepage`, there is a mistake with your route definition.

My guess it that the route name is not `homepage`, maybe because of a prefix automatically added due to use of the `AppBundle`.

Also, you are setting `always_use_default_target_path` to false, be sure that your login form doesn't contain a `_target_path` hidden field.

Comment: I used the path of the route as in `default_target_path: /` but it is not redirecting me to `deafult/index.html.twig`. I still get a blank page. Also When i browse the `homepage` route, i get the same error `No route found for "GET /homepage`

Comment: You are mixing route name and route path. You defined a route called homepage that is accessible at `http://yourhost/` because of `path="/"` in the route definition. Trying to access `/homepage` doesn't make sense. Also if you can browse the route `/` and have a blank page, the problem is coming from your template. Please add it to your question

Comment: Okay.. thanks..found the issue. The template `index.html.twig` had its contents in `{%block body%}`  and was extending `base.html.twig` which didn't have a `{%block body%}`. I added  `{%block body%}` in `base.html.twig` and it rendered. So it means route names are just identifiers and cannot be browsed right?

Comment: Right ! They are commonly used for generate urls (which can take parameters), in your templates or controllers for example.  You'll discover the point of route names as you'll use Symfony. I'll make a quick edit to add this precision.
Glad to see that you fixed your issue by yourself. Don't forget that you can (and should) accept/vote answers that help you.